Arabic movie about three boys that find a adult movie
I am looking for a movie that was Arabic and I saw it at 2003 and it seemed older than at that time.
As I remember it, it was about three boys that find a video cassette of an adult movie and the whole movie they are trying to watch it so they are looking for a place to watch it. 
and if I am not mistaken also they need a video player too.
Can some body tell me what is the name of this movie?

You're looking for the Egyptian movie Film sakafi "فيلم ثقافي" from 2001

Three sexually frustrated friends, fixated on watching a porn video. Having no private place, no VCR, and no TV, they go on a misadventure, their group increasing in numbers of sexually frustrated people as they go, falling in one mishap after the other, all because of the restrictions of society.







Here's the movie




I am not sure if this is the movie or not. if you have seen it can you tell me if this scene is in it or not? they see one their friends and want to invite him too or something like that but he is already with a girl and he declines and leaves with the the girl (girlfriend I think). I saw this movie many years ago so it may not be the exact scene. btw if this is the movie is there any subtitle for it?

May be you're thinking of this scene https://youtu.be/UqKIbLIVlIg?t=1h47m19s (They didn't invite him or anything. He's is the younger brother of one of them and that scene just shows that things might be better for him/the younger more (outgoing?)generation. And no, I can't find a subtitle for the movie.

thank you. I think this is it. is there any english subtitle to download for it?

Glad I could help, but like I said, I searched and can't find any subtitle.
